# Crash during Boot Camp restoration. How do I remove my Windows partition?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition

As mentioned in the title, my OS crashed while removing the windows partition. Now Boot Camp Assistant doesn't recognize the pre-existing Windows partition anymore. See `diskutil` results below.

How would I go about getting rid of the Windows partition and restoring everything to a single one?

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         120.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +120.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            80.5 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 46.0 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Comment: The output you posted does not show a Windows partition to get rid of. There is free space that should be added back to the APFS container.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by removing what was listed as "Free Space" in Disk Utility and re-partitioning it to Macintosh HD.

Comment: If you succeeded, then you must have added the free space back to the APFS container, not the  Macintosh HD volume. I say this because the APFS container is a partition, where as the Macintosh HD volume is not. I assume Windows no longer appears in the Startup Manager or in the Startup Disk pain of the System Preferences application.